# Data flow workers writing to GCS bucket in a different region

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My data flow workers are in region asia and they are writing avro files to a gcs bucket in region us. There is going to be network cost because of the inter-region transaction of data. AvroIO first creates temporary files before copying these temporary files to the final destination.

1. If both the temp directory and destination directory are in the
   same buckets in us region, will I incur twice the network cost
   because of the workers in asia trying to create temp files first and
   then copying the temp files?
2. Is it better to have the temp directory of AvroIO in asia region and its destination directory in us?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct - if your workers are in Asia and you are reading from a bucket in the US, you are incurring in additional network costs. Maximizing locality will mitigate that cost.

Good luck!